# Series convergence $\frac{(z+2i)^n+(z-i)^n}{n^2 \cdot 2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you tell me what can I do to determine convergence of $\frac{(z+2i)^n+(z-i)^n}{n^2 \cdot 2^n}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should try when you see a sum is to prove the convergence of each term separately:

$\cfrac{(z+2i)^n}{n^2 \cdot 2^n}=\cfrac{1}{n^2}\left(\cfrac{z+2i}{2}\right)^n$

which tells you

$\cfrac{(z+2i)^n}{n^2 \cdot 2^n} \text{ converges} \Leftrightarrow \left|\cfrac{z+2i}{2}\right|\le 1 \Leftrightarrow |z-(-2i)| \le 2$

---

The same thing for the other operand tells you that

$\cfrac{(z-i)^n}{n^2 \cdot 2^n} \text{ converges} \Leftrightarrow \left|\cfrac{z-i}{2}\right|\le 1 \Leftrightarrow |z-i| \le 2$

---

If $z$ is in both disks, then you sequence converges. If it is in one of the disks, but not in the other disk, then it diverges. If it is in neither of the disks, we don't know yet.

---

(From this point on, it's just me rewriting what Did said in the comment)

If both diverge (we are outside of both disks), the only way the sum could converge would be to have $|z+2i|=|z-i|>2$ which means $\exists x \in \Bbb R, z=x-\cfrac{1}{2}i$ with $|x|>\cfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$

$\cfrac{(z+2i)^n+(z-i)^n}{n^2 \cdot 2^n}=\cfrac{\left(x+\cfrac{3}{2}i\right)^n+\left(x-\cfrac{3}{2}i\right)^n}{n^2 \cdot 2^n}=\cfrac{2\Re\left(\left(x+\cfrac{3}{2}i\right)^n\right)}{n^2 \cdot 2^n}=\Re\left(\cfrac{2}{n^2}\left(\cfrac{x+\cfrac{3}{2}i}{2}\right)^n\right)=\Re\left(\cfrac{2}{n^2}\left(\cfrac{x}{2}+\cfrac{3}{4}i\right)^n\right)$

But since $\left|x+\cfrac{3}{2}i\right| > 2$, $\cfrac{2}{n^2}\left(\cfrac{x+\cfrac{3}{2}i}{2}\right)^n$ diverges so its real part or its imaginary part or both diverge.

---

Suppose the real part converges.

Write $x+\cfrac{3}{2}i=re^{i\theta}$

We get that $r^n\cos(n\theta)$ converges where $r>2$ so $\cos(n\theta)\to 0$

We know that $\cos(n\theta + \theta)=\cos(n\theta)\cos(\theta)-\sin(n\theta)\sin(\theta)$

By taking the limit as $n\to +\infty$, we get

$\sin(n\theta)\sin(\theta)\to 0$ Since $\Im(re^{i\theta})=\cfrac{3}{2}\not = 0$, we know that $\sin(\theta)\not=0$

So we get that $\sin(n\theta)\to 0$ so $e^{in\theta}=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)\to 0$ which is absurd since $\left|e^{in\theta}\right|=1$

So the real part diverges.

---

To conclude, it $z$ is in both disks, the sequences converges and if $z$ is outside at least one of the disks, it diverges.

Comment: The only case which could imply convergence although $z$ is in neither of these disks is if $|z+2i|=|z-i|\gt2$. Thus $z=x-\frac12i$ with $|x|\gt\frac12\sqrt7$ and the numerator is $(x+\frac32i)^n+(x-\frac32i)^n=2\Re(w^n)$ with $w=x+\frac32i$. Furthermore, $|w|\gt2$... Can you catch up from there?

Comment: Well, this would tell us that the numerator behaves in the same way as $2^n$, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Did: Nope :/ I don't know how to prove it isn't just the imaginary part that diverges...

Comment: Write $w=r\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}$ and $\Re(w^n)=r^n\cos(nt)$ with $r\gt2$. Thus, the only way convergence could occur is if $\cos(nt)\to0$. But if $\cos(nt)\to0$, $\cos((n+1)t)-\cos(t)\cos(nt)\to0$ hence $\sin(t)\sin(nt)\to0$. If $\sin t\ne0$, this means that $\sin(nt)\to0$... Can you finish?

Comment: Could you tell me why the fact that the real part converges implies that $r^n\cos(n\theta)$ converges?

Comment: $\Re((re^{i\theta})^n)=\Re(r^ne^{in\theta})=r^n\Re(e^{in\theta})=r^n\cos(n\theta)$

Comment: Ok, I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: One more question: Could you explain to me why if $z$ is in one of the disks, but not in the other disk, then the series diverges? Is it because sum of a convergent and divergent series is divergent? And why if both diverge, the only way their sum could converge would be to have $|z+2i|=|z-i|>2$?

Comment: For the first question, yes. Except that it's about sequences, not series. Series are a specific kind of sequences.

Comment: Then, for the second question, it's because if you have $a^n+b^n$ with $|a|>1,|b|>1$, you need them to compensate each other if you want the sum to converge. But if $|a|\not=|b|$, then one of them will get way bigger than the other one and so they won't compensate each other. If $|a|>|b|$, $a^n+b^n = a^n(1+\cfrac{b^n}{a^n})$ and $\cfrac{b^n}{a^n}\to 0$